# stack class in Python

Tags: python, class, stack

I have written the below code to implement the stack class instead of using the build in function, not sure if I have got it rigth. Can someone please check for me and advise if there is an error?

```
class DSAStack():

    maxCap = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

        self.count = 0


    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return false


    def isFull(self):
        if self.count == maxCap:
            return True
        else:
            return false


    def push(self, item):
        if self.isFull:
            raise ('Stack is full...')
        else:
            self.stack[self.count] = item
            self.count += 1


    def pop(self):
        self.topVal = self.top
        self.stack[self.count - 1] = 0
        self.count = self.count - 1

        return self.topVal


    def top(self):
        if self.isEmpty:
            raise ('Stack is empty...')
        else:
            self.top = self.stack[self.count - 1]
```

Comment: you want to use "==" instead of "="  in comparison (look at your if statements).....

Comment: Why does the `__init__` method take parameters that it doesn't use?

Comment: `self.count` is always equal to `len(self.stack)`, so `isFull()` will always return `true`.

Comment: What's the difference between `self.topVal` used in `pop()`  and `self.top` used in `top()`. Also, you shouldn't assign an attribute with the same name as a method, it will replace the method.

Comment: you have an indentation error in `pop()`.

Comment: So the answer to your question is that you have lots of errors.

Comment: Your `isXXX` functions should return `false` when the condition is not true. You can just use `return <condition>` rather than `if <condition>: return True`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your advise. I have modified my code based on  your advise. Not quite sure about your comment on topVal though.

Comment: It seems like you're using `self.topVal` just as a temporary variable. It doesn't need to be a class attribute, it should be an ordinary variable.

Comment: Using `top` as both a method and an attribute won't work; you probably want to `return` the value out of the `top` method. Then you need to call it in the `pop` method.

Comment: @Barmar I do run into the problem of isfull is always true, how to sort that problem     14 #test 2 - push value
     15 numtests += 1
---> 16 s.push(100)
     17 s.push(200)
     18 if s.getcount() ==2:

<ipython-input-10-e876b470f184> in push(self, value)
     21     def push(self,value):
     22         if self.isFull:
---> 23             raise Exception ('Stack is full...')
     24         else:
     25             temp = self.count

Exception: Stack is full...

Comment: Why would the stack ever be full? There's no limit to the size.

Comment: @Barmar, i have modified my code, please see the updated version, that created this new issue.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question when someone has already answered it. I've removed your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need not keep track of count. Accessing the length of the list will do that for you.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.stack =[]
```

Now, your logic for isEmpty and isFull was alright, but since we are removing the self.count variable, here's how you'd go about it

```
def isEmpty(self):
    return len(self.stack) == 0 #Directly return true or false

def isFull(self):
    return len(self.stack) == maxCap #Directly return true or false
```

In your push function, there  are a few things I'd like to point out.
First, you need to call the `isFull` function. So we need to add parentheses to it.

Secondly, you cant just `raise ('Stack is full...')`, you will get a `TypeError: Exceptions must derive from BaseException`. This basically means what you raise must be some type of error.

Lastly, you can't add a new element by doing `self.stack[self.count]=item` since you will get an `IndexError`

Here are the changes:

```
def push(self,item):
    if self.isFull():    #Need to call the function, self.isFull is not a variable
        raise Exception('Stack is full...') #Or any other type of error
    else:
        self.stack.append(item)    #Adds new item to the end of self.stack
```

Now coming to the `pop` function, setting a value to zero in a list does not really get rid of it. And it can cause a lot of confusion, especially since we are using the `len(self.stack)` to implement this.
Here's how you would pop:

```
def pop(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
        raise Exception('Stack is empty...')
    else:
        return self.stack.pop() #List has a built-in pop method
```

So now we don't really need the `top` function. And that concludes that. Btw, in your top function, you have defined `self.top = self.stack[self.count-1]`
Giving the same name to a function and a variable is never really a good idea.

To implement the pop functionality yourself, you could do the following:

```
def pop(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
        raise Exception('Stack is empty...')
    else:
        topVal = self.stack[-1] #-1 gives you the last element
        #if stack will contain objects instead of primitive data types, use self.stack[-1].copy()
        del self.stack[-1] #Deletes the element
        return topVal
```

Polishing your top function will be like this:

```
def top(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
        raise Exception('Stack is empty...')
    else:
        return self.stack[-1]
def pop(self):
    topVal = self.top()
    del self.stack[-1]    
    return topVal
```

Note how the `top` function is defined before the `pop` function.
Also, try to test the code out and resolving any issues.

Comment: thanks heaps. Your answer is very helpful. The reason I do not use the pop inbulid function is this is part of my assignment requiement. The same for the top function. Can you please polish my top function if possible?

Comment: brilliant, that make sense. Why do I need to add .copy() if it is a stack of objects?

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong seems like you don't need that 

Comment: i have modified my code a bit ,but when i run the test, the below error show up.       #test 2 - push value
     15 numtests += 1
---> 16 s.push(100)
     17 s.push(200)
     18 if s.getcount() ==2:

<ipython-input-10-e876b470f184> in push(self, value)
     21     def push(self,value):
     22         if self.isFull:
---> 23             raise Exception ('Stack is full...')
     24         else:
     25             temp = self.count

Exception: Stack is full...

Comment: Umm okay... Can't really read this properly, do you have your code with the test cases on github??